# I cannot install PhpWord Yii

Tags: yii, phpword

I have tried to install PhpWord to yii. I have downloaded zip file and extracted it into extentions folder:

```
extenstions
--PHPWord
--PHPWord.php
```

However, I cannot make it to run. I got following error:

```
include(PHPWord.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extracting the file in extension folder, you have to import that file in controller.

```
Yii::import('ext.phpword.PHPWord');
```

Comment: Thanks, mark this as a right so other can get help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't say if it's Yii 1 or 2. They have different autoloading methods.

Second, you have extracted it into extension folder, and I assume your file where you want to include it is in a completely different folder. 
You should do it like this

```
include('/full/path/to/PHPWord.php');
```

You need either absolute or a relative path to the file (I suggest using abosulte path (the one I used as an example).

Relative path means the path to the file you want to include compared to where your file, in which you are including it, is.